# Something like margin or padding except where background doesn't draw

Tags: css, background, padding, margin

Is there something that will do what `margin` does but without the background drawing in that area? For instance, when you give an element `margin: 1em` you get a `1em` border of blank space around the element, but the background draws in that area. Is there something similar to that except where the background doesn't draw?

My problem is I'm trying to put something below three `float: left`ed `div`s and right now I can't get any spacing between that and the `float`ed divs above it. They just abut directly against each other.

The `div` that is going below the `float: left`ed `div`s has the property `clear: both`. If there was something that made that `div` have space between it and that `float`ed `div` above it then that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example will help explain (and solve) your problem?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        h1, p { background-color: #eee; margin: 10px 0; }
        div { background-color: pink; float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-right: 1px; }
        br { clear: both; display: block; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello, World!</h1>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<br />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amit...</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Margins are supposed to be transparent. I think what you're seeing here is collapsing margins. Try putting a 1px border around your divs and see what happens.

Check out the CSS 2.1 spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for:

```
border: 4px white; /* replace with your color */
```

Answer (score 1):

With floated elements the margin around elements next to them is ignored.  I think you will have to create an additional element between the floated element and the item you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is floated margin space won't always be properly respected. Use a margin/border hack where you simply set the element's color to the same color as your page background and its thickness to whatever you desire. Such as in the following post:

http://socialstreams.co/41/CSS_MarginBorder_Hack